# Injecting CSS like HTML through JavaScript into the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm wondering if I can add CSS code as a string the way I can add HTML code through JavaScript, e.g.:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML =
  '<div id="hs1"></div>\n' +
  '<div id="hs2"></div>\n' +
  '<div id="hs3"></div>\n'

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Can I, in a similar fashion, add a giant CSS code?

Basically I have HTML + CSS + JS code, that I want to put into a `.js` file instead of a `.html`.
I'm new to web development, so I don't know. Is this even possible?

Comment: Just make your .css and .js files external and import them into the HTML view.

Comment: html+css to put in JS ?

Comment: Yes, have you tried creating a `<style>` tag, populating it with rules, and injecting it?

Comment: @RyanWilson I want to have only the .js file, without the .css. I want the .css code to go inside the .js somehow.

Comment: @zero298 I tried and it doesn't accept it cause you can't have <style> tags in a .js file

Comment: What do you mean?  Please see my answer.  I'm doing exactly what you're doing in your example but with a `<style>` tag.

Comment: @Mocktheduck Ok. Seems like overkill to me.

Comment: how about you try webpack? You can have seperate files for development and then pack them all together into one giant js file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can inject CSS through vanilla JavaScript:**

- Create a style element
- Set its content to your string with the CSS
- Add the style element to the head of the DOM

#### Example 1 (for older browser too):

```js
// get the head and create a style element
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';

// create your CSS as a string
var css = '.my-element { color: white; background: cornflowerblue; }';

// IE8 and below.
if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

// add it to the head
head.appendChild(style);
```

```html
<div class="my-element">Text</div>
```

#### Example 2 (for newer browsers):

```js
// create a style element
var style = document.createElement('style');

// add the CSS as a string
style.innerHTML = '.my-element { color: white; background: cornflowerblue; }';

// add it to the head
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

```html
<div class="my-element">Text</div>
```

#### Example 3 (ES6):

```js
// create a style element
const style = document.createElement('style');

// add the CSS as a string using template literals
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`
  .my-element { 
    color: white; 
    background: cornflowerblue; 
  }`
));

// add it to the head
const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(style);
```

```html
<div class="my-element">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, have you tried creating a `<style>` tag, populating it with rules, and injecting it?

```js
const style = document.createElement("style");
style.innerHTML = "#foo{background-color: green;}";
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

```html
<div id="foo">Foo bar</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you acutally tried?

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
  var sc = document.createElement('style');
  sc.innerHTML = "#myDiv { padding: 10px; border: 1px dashed blue; }";
  
  document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild( sc );
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  Test 123
</div>
<button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
```

If you have a *GIANT* css file. Its better so load the file itself. You can create a `style` tag like above and set the `href` attribute to load it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) interface to manipulate a stylesheet. The following example shows you how to manipulate an existing stylesheet. This method allows you to specify the position of the inserted rule instead of always appending it at the end:

```js
document.querySelector("#button-1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var sheet = document.querySelector("style").sheet;
  var color = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")";
  sheet.insertRule("p { background-color: " + color + "; }", sheet.cssRules.length);
});
```

```css
/* this stylesheet intentionally left blank */
```

```html
<button id="button-1">Modify Stylesheet</button>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum urna risus, non finibus sem fermentum eget. In at libero a justo molestie semper. Praesent sit amet massa justo. Donec aliquet lobortis justo tincidunt ultrices.</p>
```